# Pygame drawing antialiased shape and then blitting to main window

Tags: python, pygame

I want to draw antialiased shapes. I know you can use the pygame's `gfxdraw` module to accomplish this. However, it does seem to work only when drawing directly on the main window which is not suitable for me because I intend to use `masks` for collision checking.
Therefore a different `surface` is needed to create a mask that represents the circle.

How can you achieve this in pygame?

**Minimal working example:**

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame import gfxdraw

WIDHT, HEIGHT = 1200, 800
WIN = pg.display.set_mode((WIDHT, HEIGHT))

RADIUS = 80
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 200, 0)
RED = (200, 0, 0)
TRANS = (1, 1, 1)

class Circle(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,
                 radius: int,
                 pos: tuple[int, int],
                 color: tuple[int, int, int]):

        super().__init__()
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color

        self.image = pg.surface.Surface((radius*2, radius*2))
        self.image.fill(TRANS)
        self.image.set_colorkey(TRANS)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(pos[0], pos[1]))
        pg.gfxdraw.aacircle(self.image, self.rect.width//2, self.rect.height//2, radius, color)
        pg.gfxdraw.filled_circle(self.image, self.rect.width//2, self.rect.height//2, radius, color)
        self.mask = pg.mask.from_surface(self.image)

    def draw(self):
        WIN.blit(self.image, self.rect)


def main():
    circle_1 = Circle(RADIUS, (500, 500), GREEN)

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False

        WIN.fill(WHITE)

        circle_1.draw()
        pg.gfxdraw.filled_circle(WIN, 700, 500, RADIUS, RED)
        pg.gfxdraw.aacircle(WIN, 700, 500, RADIUS, RED)

        pg.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a transparent [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with the per pixel alpha format. Use the `SRCALPHA` flag:

<s>`self.image = pg.surface.Surface((radius*2, radius*2))`</s>

```py
self.image = pg.surface.Surface((radius*2, radius*2), pg.SRCALPHA)
```

However, for the highest quality, I suggest using OpenCV/[cv2](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) (e.g. [How to make a circular countdown timer in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67168804/how-to-make-a-circular-countdown-timer-in-pygame/67168896#67168896))